# how can I get isinstance() to work as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

during the process of learning python, I came across the isinstance function, but it doesn't behave the way I expected. despite putting an instance and its class as the parameters, it still returns false.

I have browsed this and some other websites, but I haven't been able to find anything regarding my exact situation. I have tested it with python 3.7.3.

This is how I have used it:

```
class bird:
    def fly():
        print("all birds fly.")
class owl(bird):
    def hoot():
        print("owls hoot.")
my_owl=owl
my_owl.fly()
my_owl.hoot()
print(isinstance(my_owl, owl))
print(isinstance(owl, my_owl))
```

I have reversed the order of the instance and the class parameters just to make sure I have covered all bases first. According to the tutorials I have read, isinstance should return True in one of the 2 cases above (first case in particular, but it returns false in both cases.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't make an instance. Hence `my_owl` is not an instance of `owl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a correct code:

```
class Bird():
    def fly(self):
        print("all birds fly.")

class Owl(Bird):
    def hoot(self):
        print("owls hoot.")

my_owl = Owl()
my_owl.fly()
my_owl.hoot()
print(isinstance(my_owl, Owl)) # >> True
```

And the explanation:

1. Try to respect the [python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), by using camel case for your class names, among other things.
2. A method should declare `self` as first parameter, unless it is a [static method](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) (but in this case, it should be declared as such).
3. `isinstance` shall take an object as first parameter, and a class (or tuple or classes) as second. Your second `isinstance` call will return a `TypeError`
4. When instantiating an object , you should add parenthesis after the class name: `my_owl  = Owl()`. If you don't, `my_owl` won't refer to an Owl object, but to the class definition of Owl.

Answer (score 3):

`my_owl=owl` makes `my_owl` an alias of the `owl` class, not an instance of `owl`. You'd need add parentheses:

```
my_owl = owl()
```

to make an instance, after which `isinstance(my_owl, owl)` will work.

Once you've done that you'll have other issues though. You'll need to add an explicit `self` parameter to your `fly` and `hoot` methods (which aren't valid instance methods otherwise) or alternatively, decorate them with [the `@staticmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) (so they don't need `self`, but can be called on both the class and instances of the class).